# Uniquely Identify the terminated thread in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

Let's say I have a list called USERS which contains USER1 and USER2.
**The maximum number of threads at a time can be the size of USERS. In this case 2.**
**And the threads created will have the same name as user**

I have another list that contains some values. In this case, let's say we have

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add("A");values.add("B");values.add("C");values.add("D");
```

USER1 and USER2 have to pick data from "values".

So we start the threads, and the maximum number of threads can be the size of the USERS which is 2.

We start two threads and assign them the first two values from the "values" list.

So as of now USER1--has--> A  and USER2--has--> B.

Now, USER2 thread finishes and USER1 still running.

As USER2 has finished. And I again need to create a New Thread to process the remaining data from "values".

So how am I supposed to know that USER2 thread has finished and create a new thread with the name of USER2.

Comment: Create a pool which contains user wise task status with some auto generated id just like log which contains status In-process and completed before and after execution of every thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how am I supposed to know that USER2 thread has finished

**1**. You need your thread to report it's termination to someone. That someone will be,

```
interface ThreadListener {
    void onThreadTerminated(String threadName);
}
```

**2**. Now create your thread such as when it terminates it reports it's status to `ThreadListener`.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    private ThreadListener listener;

    MyThread(ThreadListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(getName() + " starting execution.");
        doWork();
        listener.onThreadTerminated(getName());
    }

    public void doWork(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

**3**. Finally you need a concrete implementation of the stakeholder of the thread's status,

```
class Listener implements ThreadListener {

    public void onThreadTerminated(String threadName) {
        System.out.println(threadName + " finished execution");
    }
}
```

**4**. Use that in your program and apply your own logic,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Listener l = new Listener();
    MyThread t = new MyThread(l);
    t.setName("MyThread");
    t.start();
}
```

The output,

*MyThreadstarting execution.*

*MyThread finished execution* (after 1,5 seconds)

Comment: Thanks, Themelis for the answer but I don't think that you solved my problem. Printing the user which has finished is for us.
The issue is I want the code to know which USER has finished its task so that the next thread that I need to create to pick another "value" will be of the name of "USER2".

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you use a `BlockingQueue` rather than a list.

```
BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(list.size(), true, list);
```

Then, you start one thread for each consumer (ie in your case user) taking items from the queue until it's empty.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newThreadPoolExecutor(users.size());
for (final User user : users) {
    executor.submit(() -> {
        try {
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                String item = queue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                if (item != null) {
                    user.handle(item);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {}
    });
}
```

Now you will have submitted a number of threads equal to the number of users, each of which will keep taking items from the queue and handing it to the appropriate user, until none are left in the queue.